# PHP image crop making black images

Tags: php, image-processing

I've got a problem with this code. The code is a PHP page that receives information on where to crop the image. The sent information seems to be alright, it's coordinates (x1, y1, x2, y2), but the PHP code just makes a black image as a result. Although, it is the right scale, at least.

I am quite fresh when it comes to php, so sorry if this is something basic, but i just can't find an answer :/

image-cropping php:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    $targ_w = $_POST['w'];
    $targ_h = $_POST['h'];
    $jpeg_quality = 90;

    $src = $_POST['img_file'];
    $img_r = imagecreatefromjpeg($src);
    $dst_r = ImageCreateTrueColor( $targ_w, $targ_h );

    imagecopyresampled($dst_r,$img_r,0,0,$_POST['x1'],$_POST['y1'],
    $targ_w,$targ_h,$_POST['w'],$_POST['h']);

    header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
    imagejpeg($dst_r,$src,$jpeg_quality);

    exit;
}
elseif($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET'){
    $src_g = './demo2/pics/' . $_GET['id'] . 'v' . $_GET['v'] . '.jpg';
    if(!file_exists($src_g)){
        die();
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: My bad for not mentioning it. I am trying to save the edited image on disc for future use. And it does make a jpg file, but it is just a black rectangle.

Comment: To upload a file you must have a form with `enctype="multipart/form-data"` as an attribute. And the file will then be accessed through the `$_FILES` array not `$_POST`. Enable error_reporting and I guess you will get an error when calling `imagecreatefromjpg()` since the file doesn't exist.

Comment: Oh!.. that makes sense... It's a black rectangle because it doesn't even get the picture. Thanks for such a quick answer, gonna try and fix it now.

Comment: A good approach when developing is to always have error_reporting turned on, add the following at the top of your script: `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like I said in my comment you must set `enctype` to `multipart/form-data` in order for your form to support file uploads. Here is an example of a working form:

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="file" id="file" />
  <input type="text" name="x1" value="0" />
  <input type="text" name="y1" value="0" />
  <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
```

Then you will check if the `$_FILES` array are set and then modify the image and output it to the browser:

```
// enable error reporting
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', true);

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' && 
   isset($_FILES['file']) && 
   $_FILES['file']['error'] == 0) {

   // create an image resource from the temporary file
   $src = imagecreatefromjpeg($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
   // get dimensions of the source image
   $src_w = imagesx($src);
   $src_h = imagesy($src);

   // get offset to copy from 
   $src_x = intval($_POST['x1']);
   $src_y = intval($_POST['y1']);
   $dst_w = $src_w - $src_x;
   $dst_h = $src_h - $src_y;

   // create destination image 
   $dst = imagecreatetruecolor($dst_w, $dst_h);

   // copy the original image based on offset to destination
   // notice that we subtract the offset from the source width and hight
   // so we use `$dst_w` && `$dst_h`
   imagecopyresampled($dst, 
                      $src, 0, 0, 
                      $src_x, $src_y, 
                      $dst_w, $dst_h, 
                      $dst_w, $dst_h);
   // destroy resource
   imagedestroy($src);

   // output the image to the browser
   header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
   imagejpeg($dst);
   imagedestroy($dst);
   exit;
}
```

Notice that this is just a quick example and you should check for errors and so on. Like I also stated in my comment always enable `error_reporting` which often will give you information about what is going wrong. One other thing to keep in mind is that the code above assumes that the upload file is really a `.jpg` file which also is something that you probably would need to verify first.

Like you asked in your comment of course you can send a file location from the form. Then you will have to modify the code a bit:

```
if(isset($_POST['file_path']) && file_exists($_POST['file_path'])) {
   $src = $_POST['img_path'];
   $img_r = imagecreatefromjpeg($src);
```

**Reference**

[POST method uploads in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php)

Comment: If the file is already uploaded and i send it's location via `<input type="hidden" .../>` should it work with `$src = $_POST[file_path];`? I used the word _should_ instead of _would_ because it might not work for some other reason :/